# Create date field in dataframe

Tags: r

I have drafted the below code which uses the values contained within three char fields (char type) in a dataframe to create a new date field, however when I check the type of the field is a char field. 
Can anyone explain what I am doing incorrectly.

```
A$DOB_Revised<-as.Date(ISOdate(year=A$DOByear, monnth=A$DOBMonth, day=A$DOBDay))  
A$DOB_Revised<-format(A$DOB_Revised, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
```

Comment: if you use `format` it will of type character.

Comment: That is the function `format()`, not the argument within